# Поиск слов в предложении списка Python3

Tags: python-3.x, массивы, поиск, фильтр

у меня есть определенный массив слов.
Требуется чтоб в предложении он находил то слово из нужного массива и выдавал значение `True`.
Проблема в том, что если я напишу просто слово то он найдет его, а если это слово в предложении, то не найдет.

```
SlovarList = ["яблоко", "груша", "апельсин"]
message = "яблоко"
if message in SlovarList:
    print("TRUE")
```

Но если предложение будет такое: яблоко зеленое, то ничего не найдет.
Пытался переводить предложение в массивы за счет `message.split()` но не вышло, пытался сравнить массивы, тоже не получилось тк он сравнивает мой `message.split()` со всем массивом `SlovarList` сразу и выводит `False`.

Comment: `"Яблоко" != "яблоко"` ;)

Comment: слова в одном регистре ????

Comment: все слова в одном регистре, все верно

Answer (score 0):

Если слова в едином регистре - можно сделать так

```
message = "дивное мое яблоко"
SlovarList = ["яблоко", "груша", "апельсин"]

if any(word in SlovarList for word in message.split()):
    print("yeap")
```